# two device has gat Different time zone in DelayInformation TimeStamp

Tags: android, timezone

I am getting delay timezone of MUC message using DelayInformation from openfire server.

below is my code

```
DelayInformation inf = null;
try {
    inf = (DelayInformation) packet.getExtension("x",
            "jabber:x:delay");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (inf == null) {
    try {
        inf = (DelayInformation) message.getExtension(
                "delay", "urn:xmpp:delay");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
Date date;
String dateStr="";
// get offline message timestamp

if (inf != null) {
    date = inf.getStamp();
    // in 1st device   Sat Oct 18 14:10:53 IST 2014
    // in 2nd device Sat Oct 18 14:10:30 GMT+05:30 2014
    dateStr=TimeRender.getDate(date);

} else {
    dateStr=TimeRender.getDate();
}
```

When I get delay message from device 1 
my date is `Sat Oct 18 14:10:53 IST 2014`

and my 2nd device date is `Oct 18 14:10:30 GMT+05:30 2014`

I also check device date & time 
both device has `GMT +05:30, India Standard Time`
Then why I am getting two different timezone IST and GMT.

I don't understand this issue, am I missing something?

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you use Smack? If so, which version?

Comment: no i am using asmack...

Comment: i think its not dependent smack or asmack.

Comment: Yes and no. It depends on the timezone of the system producing the time stamps. For example one could be produced by (a)Smack on a client which timezone is set to 'IST', while the other could be produced by an XMPP server which system timezone is set to 'GMT'.

Comment: but i use same code and jar in my both device

Comment: How's that statement relevant to the device's timezone?

Comment: yes, please read my question again so you understand my problem.

Comment: in setting both device same time zone

Comment: @Flow can you help me in this qu. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754832/openfire-connecting-exception-remote-server-error502-xmpperror-connecting-to