# Openfire Connecting Exception: remote-server-error(502) xmpperror connecting to 5222

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, asmack

I working on chatApp. i am successfully implement xmpp chat using oenfire server past 2 month using asmack.
but few hour ago i get below exception and till now i am unable to contact server.

**192.168.0.1:5222 Exception: XMPPError connecting to 192.168.0.1:5222.; : remote-server-error(502)**

i try to find solution on google, but not get any success,

below code using for contact openfire

```
ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                    Constants.TEST_HOST, Constants.PORT,
                    Constants.TEST_SERVICE);
            con = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

            SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN");
            connConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
            con.connect();
```

how can i fix this problem. Thanks for help in advance

Comment: have you define internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: yes, if i not set internet permission then i get error for internet permission. and i do successful chat from past two month but never get this error but past 5 hour ago i get this error

Comment: is issue from server side

Comment: @Lokesh Were you able to resolve what was the cause behind it as I am facing the same.

Comment: @Kanchan i post my answer. try this

Comment: you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804236/why-cant-i-connect-to-the-openfire-server <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Comment: already resolved bro, in my case firewall permissions not allow to connect sever.

Answer (score 0):

After many research on this issue.
i found to reason for this as above.

**1. may be your firewall permissions not allow to connect sever.**

**2. may your socket setting or ip of server is change.**

In my case-
i restart my server. and remove firewall setting. Its resolved my problem

so please check your sever socket setting, server ip address  and firewall permissions.

and also make sure that server with port 5222 (for device and 9090 for browser ) is always enable.

Comment: and also check your Internet connection of server as well as device side.

Comment: @Kanchan please check port and url are correct and also check server side setting.

Comment: i mean can you access server from other desktop machine using that  hosturl:9090

Comment: It was working fine yesterday . Today suddenly it started giving me above error !

Comment: It is working on other desktop machine too with hosturl:9090.

Comment: ok, but restart server is works for me. and let me check this issue.

Comment: ok thanks for sharing all the above solutions . I will get back to you if my problem get solved .

Comment: hello Lokesh actually the problem is that we changed our router so some setting need to be made there to make the ip accessible by the device . BTW do you know about these settings ?

Comment: make your server ip as static then can done by your network provider company, contact him they make your server static ip

Comment: ok I will get that done. Thanks for helping me out with this error !